# PHP replace … with

Tags: php, string, encoding, multibyte

I have a txt file (File encoded in ANSI according to Notepad++) that has '…' in it. I am reading in the file line by line, and I would like to replace `…` with `...`

Everything I try seems to fail

1. `$str = htmlentities($str); # trying to convert to &hellip; as I can deal with this`
2. `$str = mb_ereg_replace("…","...",$str);`
3. `$str = str_replace("…", "...", $str);`

**All of the above aren't working! What am I missing and how can I fix this issue?**

**NOTE:** My php script that is trying to fix this is encoded in UTF8 and the php header is UTF8

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you open the `txt` file in a hex editor, what bytes represent the `…`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said it is represented with the byte `0x85` in the file, try this:

```
$str = str_replace("\x85", "...", $str);
```